# "Fail to fsync the AOF file: Input/output error" with Bitnami redis helm chart

Tags: input, redis, output, fsync

Using the [Bitnami redis helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis) version 17.7.5 on Kubernetes version 1.24, we sometimes unexpectedly run into the error: Unhealthy: Readiness probe failed: MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: Input/output error MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: Input/output error

As far as I can tell, the errors happen nondeterministically.

What could be causing this error?  If it's too general, what are ways that I can further debug this issue myself?  Happy to provide more information if needed.

I've tried upgrading chart/redis versions, looking at resource consumption around the time of failure, digging through node syslogs, but so far no luck.